# Flash a ROM without using recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, flashtool

I have an LG Prada 3.0 p940, running Android 2.3.7.

I have a problem accessing recovery mode. Is it possible to flash CyanogenMod ROM on stock ROM through PC without installing custom recovery?

Does anyone know a software that is trustworthy to do that, or to back up my current ROM?

Comment: What phone is it?, try to be more specic

Comment: Try LG Flash Tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can not delete the system while it is running. If you have root access, you could "program" the stock recovery to flash your custom ROM on the next reboot by using a specific command line in a terminal.

There is [LG Flash Tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2797190) for your device, but it is not official.